# My nameservers do not provide DNSSEC information with their answers- problem?

Tags: domain-name-system, dnssec

Some of our users have reported having issues accessing our website ("no response"). Suspecting a DNS issue we have performed some online tests that return only this warning:

```
Your nameservers do not provide DNSSEC information with their answers
; no DNSKEY from ns1.example.com.
; no RRSIG recs from ns1.example.com.
```

My question: is this likely to prevent access to any clients?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  DNSSEC is really in the infancy of an actual implementation; nothing's going to block you if your zone isn't signed.

Depends on the browser, but a "no response" error sounds like it could resolve the name but didn't get a response to connection attempts; maybe have clients who are having issues send you the result of a traceroute?